# Accessing nested JSON value

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to access a certain value from a JSON object.  The value I am trying to access is launches->rocket->agencies->abbrev from a JSON object that has a lot of nested objects and arrays. I can't access values below a certain nested level for some reason.  Here is a screenshot of the JSON object logged in the console.

[JSON Object screenshot http://prntscr.com/c6ym11](http://prntscr.com/c6ym11)
Edit: [Link to the image, since embedding didn't work](http://prnt.sc/c6ym11)

[Here is a link to an example of the JSON formatting in the returned data](http://ccs-strategies.com/data/LaunchLibraryFormat.json)

These are the ways I have tried:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
var agency = [];
var names = [];
var configuration = [];

for(i = 0; i < data.launches.length; i++){
    //This works just fine
    names.push(data.launches[i].name);

    //This also works
    configuration.push(data.launches[i].rocket.configuration);

    //This returns undefined
    agency.push(data.launches[i].rocket.agencies.abbrev); 

    //This generates Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'abbrev' of undefined
    agency.push(data.launches[i].rocket.agencies[0].abbrev); 
}
```

I can access key:value pairs on the "rocket" level, but I cannot access anything nested below that level.  Is there something wrong with how I am calling the data?

Comment: With your example json it would work. So you most likely have a part of json that you didn't show where agencies[0] is not there. https://jsfiddle.net/8oeu7qsm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the structure of the json object it looks like you need an index off of the agencies. The last line of your code example should work.

I would imagine you would want something like

```
for(j = 0; j < data.launches[i].rocket.agencies.length; j++){
  agency.push(data.launches[i].rocket.agencies[j].abbrev);
}
```

This way if there are no agencies you will not get the error

Comment: Thanks.  Syntax is a little off, but I was able to tweak it enough to make it work!  Makes sense that I need another loop to determine the index of the agencies object.

Comment: No problemo! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
for(i = 0; i < data.launches.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < data.launches[i].rocket.agencies.length; j++){
    company.push(data.launches[i].rocket.agencies[j].abbrev);
    };
}
```